# How do I find the exact solution to complete elliptic integral of the second kind?

Tags: conic-sections, elliptic-integrals

I tried to find the solution from the internet; but every website I tried just gave me this as the result:

[image: From integral-calculator.com]

So what's the exact solution? I don't want to just get $E(\theta|k^2)$ as the result.

Comment: What would you like to have? $E(\theta|k^2)$ is a function which is known, you can also calculate its approximate values. Since the integral does not give an answer in "simple" functions (polynomial, trigonometric function), and because this form of integral appears often enough, it was decided to define a new function, in fact a class of new functions, the "elliptical integrals".

Comment: @BernardMassé You mean there's no alternative function for $E(\theta|k^2)$?

Comment: There's also series expansion for it; but that changes for every single $k$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral

Comment: @Intelligentipauca That Wikipedia article is a little hard to understand; also, when that's $E(\phi|k^2)$ it should be $\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2{\phi}}$, not $\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2{\theta}}$.

Comment: Look more carefully. That definition is correct, because $\theta$ is the variable of integration.